# How to make docker daemon (dockerd) run on boot?

Tags: linux, docker, startup

I installed docker, but when restarting I have to manually ran `dockerd`.

How to make it run on start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not easily searchable from Google, so posting it here for easy Googling.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot)

```
 sudo systemctl enable docker.service
 sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```

To disable this behavior, use disable instead.

```
 sudo systemctl disable docker.service
 sudo systemctl disable containerd.service
```